# I want to snyc the questions with scriptDB in a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Form script and need to store extra settings for each question.  I want to avoid creating a spreadsheet so I am trying to use scriptDB to store the settings for each question.  (If there is a better way please let me know).

Right now I am just trying to create a synchronizeDB() function that will update the Database with any new or deleted questions.  I can't just delete and reload because that would delete the extra data I stored for each question.

-bj

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
function snycFormToDb(){

  var formQs = getFormQarray();
  addDBQuestions(formQs);
  removeDBQuestions(formQs);
//  showAll();

}


// Save Questions To DB
function getFormQarray(){
 var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
 var items = form.getItems();
 var itemL = items.length-1;
 var allQuestions = [];

  for (var i=0; i <= itemL; ++i) {
    var qID = items[i].getId();
    var qType = items[i].getType()+ "";
    var qTitle =  items[i].getTitle();
    var qIndex=  items[i].getIndex();
    var qHelpTxt =  items[i].getHelpText();

    var entry = [qID,qIndex,qTitle,qType,qHelpTxt];
    allQuestions.push(entry);

  } // end For    

  return(allQuestions);
};  // end function questionsDB()




// Add questions to DB
function addDBQuestions(formQs) {

  var dbQuestions = [];
  var results = db.query({});   
  while (results.hasNext()) {
  var current = results.next();
  dbQuestions.push(current); 
  }

  var dbQuestionsL = dbQuestions.length-1;
  var formQsL = formQs.length-1;
  var addToDb = [];

 for (var j=0; j <= formQsL; ++j) {
   var notPresent = false;
   for (var k=0; k <= dbQuestionsL; ++k) {

      var dbID = dbQuestions[k]['qID'];
      var frmID = formQs[j][0];
      if (dbID == frmID){
        notPresent = true;       
      }
   }
   if (notPresent == false) {
     //var entry = [qID,qIndex,qTitle,qType,qHelpTxt]; 
     //var format = {type: formQs[j][2],title: formQs[j][1],qID: formQs[j][0]};
     var format = {qID: formQs[j][0],qIndex: formQs[j][1],qTitle: formQs[j][2],qType: formQs[j][3],qHelpTxt: formQs[j][4]};
     addToDb.push(format);
   }
 } // end for formQsL
  db.saveBatch(addToDb, false);
   } //end my function



// Remove Q's from Database
function removeDBQuestions(formQs) {

 var formQsL = formQs.length-1;

  //get qID results from Database 
  var results = db.query({});   
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var current = results.next();
    //var recordID = results.getId();
    var deleteCurrent = "true";

    // Delete missing questions
    for (var j=0; j <= formQsL; ++j) {
       var c1 = current.qID;
       var c2 = formQs[j][0];
       if (current.qID == formQs[j][0]){ deleteCurrent = "false";}
     }

    if (deleteCurrent == "true"){
      db.remove(current);
    }
  }

} //end my function
```